# OCR Customer Invoices

Tags: image, pdf, odoo, account, invoice

Is there any examples how to develop OCR module in Odoo to read customer invoices from pdf/images. Please someone guide with the possibilities or links showing the example to develop such module. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Odoo already has this feature in enterprise version.

Refer https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/applications/finance/accounting/payables/supplier_bills/ocr.html

Look into these modules

```
 account_invoice_extract 
 account_invoice_extract_purchase
```

Comment: I will add that the OCR is a REST API, so you can use it outside of Odoo or even in community. You can find the documentation here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/api/extract_api.html